# the set of all bit patterns that can be placed in a desired register using a single instruction

Tags: mips, instruction-set, mips32, mips64

Given the following set of MiniMIPS instructions:

```
Load upper immediate
Add
Subtract
Set less than
Add immediate
Set less than immediate
Add
OR
XOR
NOR
AND immediate
OR immediate
XOR immediate
Load word
Store word
```

In MiniMips instructions, It's possible for some actions such as initializing a register to zero-bit pattern (all bits are zero) to have more than one instruction with the ability of doing that.

My question is, What are the set of all bit patterns that can be placed in a desired register using a single instruction from the given instruction set.

Answer (score 0):

Since you allow "load word" and you include MIPS64 in your tags, the answer is **any** 64 bit integer can be loaded into a register using a single instruction from your instruction list.

Comment: Which instruction is that? Can you please elaborate more? What if I am using Mips32?

Comment: That was the `Load word (LW)` instruction. If you are using MIPS32, then any 32 bit integer can be loaded with the Load word instruction.

Comment: in MIPS64 you need `load double word` to load 64-bit values, `load word` can only loads 32-bit ones